# Connection timed out on Node.js app running under CentOS

Tags: centos, node.js

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit) to create a simple node.js app on my CentOS:

the node.js version is:

```
$ node -v 
v0.10.28
```

Here's my `app.js`:

```
// Include http module, 
var http = require("http"), 
// And url module, which is very helpful in parsing request parameters. 
    url = require("url"); 
// show message at console
console.log('Node.js app is running.'); 
// Create the server. 
http.createServer(function (request, response) { 
    request.resume();
    // Attach listener on end event. 
    request.on("end", function () { 
        // Parse the request for arguments and store them in _get variable. 
        // This function parses the url from request and returns object representation. 
        var _get = url.parse(request.url, true).query; 
        // Write headers to the response. 
        response.writeHead(200, { 
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }); 
        // Send data and end response. 
        response.end('Here is your data: ' + _get['data']); 
    }); 
// Listen on the 8080 port. 
}).listen(8080);
```

However, when I uploaded this app onto my remote server (assume the address is 123.45.67.89), I couldn't get access to it on my browser

`http://123.45.67.89:8080/?data=123`

The browser returned `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I tried the same app.js code which runs fine on my local machine, is there anything I am missing?

I tried to `ping` the server and its address was reachable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you didn't open your firewall for port 8080. You can do this using the [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) command

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

If this works you can save your firewall state with

```
service iptables save
```